# Using xlwings to open excel sheet. Need to search a string and print full line

Tags: python, excel, string, pandas, xlwings

I'm using xlwings to open excel sheet. Need to search a string in a specific column and print full line of the string without search item and until new line(\n). Output should be in new column of same sheet.

Input:

[image]

search string: [game]
Output:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

```
import xlwings as xw
```

open `excel` file using `xlwings`

```
filename = r'input.xlsx'
book = xw.Book(filename)
sheet = book.sheets[0]
```

find the `last row` of the `sheet` on a specific range in this case from `column 'A'`

```
lrow = sheet.range('A' + str(sheet.cells.last_cell.row)).end('up').row
```

declare a separate variable for the `string` that you will search and the `column` where your output will be located.

```
search_string = '[game]'
sheet.range('B1').value = 'output'
output_index = 2
```

now loop through that range to see if your search_string is in that range

```
for i in range(1, lrow + 1):
    if search_string in str(sheet.range('A{}'.format(i)).value):
        temp = str(sheet.range('A{}'.format(i)).value)
        temp = temp.split(search_string)[1]
        if '[' in temp:
            temp = temp.split('[')[0]
        sheet.range('B{}'.format(output_index)).value = temp
        output_index += 1


book.save()
book.close()
```

Below is the full code >>

```
import xlwings as xw
filename = r'input.xlsx'

book = xw.Book(filename)
sheet = book.sheets[0]
lrow = sheet.range('A' + str(sheet.cells.last_cell.row)).end('up').row
search_string = '[game]'
sheet.range('B1').value = 'output'
output_index = 2

for i in range(1, lrow + 1):
    if search_string in str(sheet.range('A{}'.format(i)).value):
        temp = str(sheet.range('A{}'.format(i)).value)
        temp = temp.split(search_string)[1]
        if '[' in temp:
            temp = temp.split('[')[0]
        sheet.range('B{}'.format(output_index)).value = temp
        output_index += 1


book.save()
book.close()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. Below are output of your code:                                           
list output
"[game] chess 
[person] kum" "chess
[person] kum"
"[Team] india
[game] cricket
[person]dho" "[Team] india
 cricket
[person]dho"

Comment: It's not removing below line of [game] same cell. I want only " **chess** " but I'm getting " **chess [person] kum** "

Comment: the code is edited you can try again @ARAVINTHKUMARJ

Comment: Thank you.. But all output come with '\n'. Like after **chess** there is an **Enter** in my cell. Can you pls help remove that.


One more thing: 
Input: [game] [india] chess
Output: [india] chess   ... but now I'm not getting anything (It's empty). I want remove only search string.

 Can you pls help me on this also.

Comment: if '\n' in temp:
            temp = temp.split('\n')[0]

After this change from ur code.. It's working.
Thank u.!

Comment: Hi,
`lrow = sheet.range('A' + str(sheet.cells.last_cell.row)).end('up').row`

Instandof mentioning 'A', How can I mention column header `**list**`.

Comment: you can add this to find the range that has the list key word

`start_cell = sheet.api.UsedRange.Find('list')`  
then this line to extract the column character
`start_column = str(start_cell.Address).replace('$','')[:1]`

just use the 'start_column' variable to find the last row
`lrow = sheet.range(start_column + str(sheet.cells.last_cell.row)).end('up').row`